# prove this equality

Tags: calculus, power-series

[image]

First, I try to use the Taylor series but it doesn't work well.
And someone said I can use fundamental theorem of calculus but I don't see it.

can anyone give me a good hit?

thanks

Comment: $(n)$ is the nth-derivative?

Comment: that n means n power

Comment: No it doesn't; it definitely means the $n$-th derivative. Have you tried evaluating the first couple of derivatives of the left hand side?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start:

Let
$f_n( x)
=D_n(x^{n-1}e^{1/x})
$,
where $D_n$ 
is the $n^{th}$
derivative.

By Leibnitz's formula
$D_n(a(x)b(x))
=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{ k} D_k(a(x))D_{n-k}(b(x)) 
$.
(This is readily proved by induction
using the regular product rule
for derivatives.)

Then get the appropriate derivatives.

Note that many of the derivatives
may be zero,
which might simplify things.